# building patchwork plot programmatically

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

All of the patchwork documentation describes building a plot with
p1+p2+p3+p4 (or p1 | p2 | ...)

I would like to build a patchwork plot from a list of ggplot objects, where I do not know the number of plots in advance.

I can make a list of plots, and make the final page with:

`final.plot <- p_list[[1]] | p_list[[2]] | p_list[[3]]`

But I have not figured out how to make a plot with

```
final.plot <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(p_list)){
  final.plot <- final.plot | p_list[[i]]
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To programmatically create a `patchwork` from a `list` of plots the `patchwork` package provides `patchwork::wrap_plots()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p_list <- replicate(4, ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point(), simplify = FALSE)

p_list |> 
  wrap_plots(ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Or instead of a `for` loop use `Reduce` but I don't see any reason to so as we have `wrap_plots()`:

```r
p_list |> 
  Reduce(`|`, x = _) +
  plot_layout(ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: The second option can be simplified as: ```Reduce('|',p_list) + plot_layout()```

Comment: Sure. in that case you could drop the `plot_layout()` altogether. Was just meant to show set we can still set the number of rows/cols.